# Can 3000+ callories cause diarrhea?

Tags: diet, muscle-gain

I'm eating over 3000+(eat mostly buckwheat, rice, pilaf, pork, pork chops and boiled eggs). And I'm taking a few supplements(nitrobolon and hmb by Trec).

Can something in my diet cause diarrhea or something like that? Maybe I can improve my diet?

My goal is build more muscle gain and weight

Edit:
My weight: 205lbs
My height: 6ft 2.5in

My workout: I don't know how to describe it correctly
My workout langth:1hr-1.2hr
Trying to lift off as much as possible weight to achive more muscle stress

Reverse grip bent over row: 220lbs x 8reps(242lbs x 3 is my maximum)
Curl barbell: 110lbs x10reps
Deep squats: 198x 6reps
Dumbbell incline bench press: 66lbs x 5reps(yep I'm suck at press)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your diet is low in fibre and vitamins. Both deficits are unhealthy, and at least the first one can lead to diarrhoea. You did not specify your training, or weight, which makes it hard to assess your situation.

Comment: Diarrhea isn't so much caused by the caloric amount, but rather the products themselves. And it differs from person to person based on intolerances and digestive "preferences". So there is no one-size-fits-all answer to this question.

Comment: Also, this question might get closed because the actual exercise part is very vague and intangible. You should be much more detailed in the information you give about your training. As a rule of thumb, spend as much time writing the question as you'd want someone to spend on an answer.

Comment: If you've made a mass change to your diet lately, you might need some time to adjust. I'd also watch the quantity of that Nitrobolon supplement. Creatine, in excess, disagrees with a lot of people's stomachs. Glutamine is used as a gut health supplement as well.